# Differential operator for an Integral transform

Tags: integral-transforms, differential-operators

Given an integral transform $(Tf)(x)=\int_{\Bbb R^d} K(x,y)f(y)dy$, with $K(x,y)=K(y,x)$, how can I find the associated differential operator?

If it helps, I am especially interested in $K(x,y)=e^{-Q(x,y)}$ with $Q(x,y)$ being a polynomial involving only the monomials of the form $x_i^ay_j^b$, with $a+b=2$.

Comment: To clarify, are you seeking a differential operator $L=\sum a_\alpha(x)\partial_x^\alpha$ such that $LK(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$? (i.e. that $K$ is a Green's kernel of $L$?)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Does $Q$ depend on some parameter $t$, in a non-smooth way?  If not, then such an operator does not exist, since $Q$ is smooth.  The heat kernel $(x,y)\mapsto K_t(x-y)$ is an example.  Its dependence on $t$ is not smooth, so it is the fundamental solution to $(\partial_t-\Delta)$.  However, we cannot find an operator $\sum_{\alpha}a_{\alpha}(x)\partial_x^\alpha$ for which $K_t(x-y)$ is the fundamental solution.